# Calculating the curvature of a closed curve ( or polygon) in matlab

Tags: matlab, computational-geometry

Consider the following set of points

```
x = [1.34, 0.92, 0.68, 0.25, -0.06, -0.34, -0.49, -0.72, -0.79, -0.94, -1.35, -0.35, 0.54, 0.68, 0.84, 1.20, 1.23, 1.32, 1.34];
y = [0.30, 0.43, 0.90, 1.40, 1.13, 1.08, 1.14, 1.23, 0.52, 0.21, -0.20, -0.73, -0.73, -0.82, -0.71, -0.76, -0.46, -0.13, 0.30];
```

That give a closed curve (or polygon):

```
figure(1)
hold on
plot(x,y,'k');
scatter(x,y,'r');
xlim([-2 2]);
ylim([-2 2]);
axis equal
```

[image]

I wish to calculate the curvature (as accurate as possible) at the points on the curve.

what I have until now is a simple calculation of the tangent vector (1st derivate) and then the curvature (2nd derivate):

```
dsx = diff(x);
dsy = diff(y);
ds = sqrt(dsx.^2+dsy.^2);
Tx = dsx./ds;
Ty = dsy./ds;
ds2 = 0.5*(ds(1:end-1)+ds(2:end));
Hx = diff(Tx)./ds2;
Hy = diff(Ty)./ds2;
```

But I get a very inaccurate curvature:

```
figure(1)
quiver(x(1:end-2),y(1:end-2),Hx,Hy,'b','autoscalefactor',1.2); 
xlim([-2 2]); ylim([-2 2]);
axis equal
```

[image]

This is suppose to be a simple calculation, however it does not work, please advice: how can I find the curvature in the simplest approximation and have a reasonable accuracy in direction and magnitude?

Comment: Your curvature is correct, by shifted by one point. `diff` computes the difference between subsequent points, leading to the scope in between points. If you apply it twice, you get second derivatives at the samples, but the result is shifted by one sample.

Comment: @CrisLuengo, tnx for your answer. Can you please provide a solution. I'll accept it, please use the example I've provided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The curvature computation is correct, it's the plotting that is off. Note that `diff` computes the difference between subsequent elements, yielding a vector with one fewer element. It estimates the derivative in between pairs of samples. If you repeat this, you'll get the second derivative at samples, but not at the first or last sample (you have 2 fewer elements now).

You did notice this, because you are plotting a curvature at all but one vertex.

So all you need to do is replicate a point after the first derivative (I'm adding the last point to the beginning, so the elements are in the same order as in the input array). The indexing statement `Tx([end,1:end])` does just that.

In the code below, I'm plotting also the normals (Ty,-Tx) in black.

```
x = [1.34, 0.92, 0.68, 0.25, -0.06, -0.34, -0.49, -0.72, -0.79, -0.94, -1.35, -0.35, 0.54, 0.68, 0.84, 1.20, 1.23, 1.32, 1.34];
y = [0.30, 0.43, 0.90, 1.40, 1.13, 1.08, 1.14, 1.23, 0.52, 0.21, -0.20, -0.73, -0.73, -0.82, -0.71, -0.76,-0.46, -0.13, 0.30];

% First derivative
dsx = diff(x);
dsy = diff(y);
ds = sqrt(dsx.^2+dsy.^2);
Tx = dsx./ds;
Ty = dsy./ds;

% Second derivative & curvature
ds2 = 0.5*(ds([end,1:end-1])+ds);
Hx = diff(Tx([end,1:end]))./ds2;
Hy = diff(Ty([end,1:end]))./ds2;

% Plot
clf
hold on
plot(x,y,'ro-');
x = x(1:end-1);
y = y(1:end-1); % remove repeated point
quiver(x+dsx/2,y+dsy/2,Ty,-Tx,'k','autoscalefactor',0.3); 
quiver(x,y,Hx,Hy,'b','autoscalefactor',1.2); 
set(gca,'xlim',[-2 2],'ylim',[-1.5 2]);
axis equal
```

[image: output of plotting commands above]

Comment: What's the connection between a "curvature" and the difference between edge direction vectors ? And what is the purpose of the statement `ds2 = 0.5*(ds+ds)` ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust: Thanks for catching that. `ds2` is supposed to be the average of the length of two neighboring edges. That is the length of edge in between neighboring normals, if you consider the normals to be half-way between vertices. I've fixed the code.

Comment: @YvesDaoust: Regarding your question about the connection between curvature and the difference between edge direction vectors: this is exactly the definition of curvature. See for example on Wikipedia, [Curvature: "Precise definition"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curvature#Precise_definition). A little bit above it has a description of what these equations mean: "Geometrically, the curvature κ measures how fast the unit tangent vector to the curve rotates."

Comment: Curvature on a sparse polygon like this might not be very meaningful, but that doesn't mean it's not possible to apply the discrete approximation to the derivative to compute it. The same code on a more densely sampled outline will give a good approximation of the curvature of the outline.

Comment: you pointed the very problem: these discrete approximations are the wrong ones. But the OP doesn't care.