# How to calculate the point-by-point radius of curvature of a trajectory that is not a proper function

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, curve

with Matlab i'm trying to calculate the "radius of curvature" signal of a trajectory obtained using GPS data projected to the local cartesian plane.
The value of the signal onthe n-th point is the one of the osculating circle tangent to the trajectory on that point.
By convention the signal amplitude has to be negative when related to a left turn and viceversa.

With trajectories having a proper function as graph i'm building the "sign" signal evaluating the numeric difference between the y coordinate of the center of the osculating circle:

```
for i=1:length(yCenter) -1
    aux=Y_m(closestIndex_head:closestIndex_tail );

    if yCenter(i) - aux(i) > 0
        sign(i)=-1;
    else
        sign(i)=+1;
        
    end
end
```

- yCenter contains x-coordinates of all osculating circles related to each point of the trajectory;
- Y_m contain the y-coordinates of every point in trajectory.

The above simple method works as long as the trajectory's graph is a proper function (for every x there is only one y).

The trajectory i'm working on is like that:

[image]

and the sign signal got some anomalies:

[image]

The sign seems to change within a turn.

I've tried to correct the sign using the sin of the angle between the tangent vector and the trajectory, the sign of the tangent of the angle and other similar stuff, but still i'm looking at some anomalies:
[image]

I'm pretty sure that those anomalies came from the fact that the graph is not a proper function and that the solution lies on the angle of the tangent vector, but still something is missing.

Any advice will be really appreciated,
thank you.

Alessandro

Comment: If you swap x and y, your graph suddenly becomes a "proper fucntion"

Comment: Of course, but i want my script to be able to compute trajectories like the one i've linked without me having to swap x and y.

Comment: You may need a [mcve] then

Comment: It is better to calculate the inverse of the curvature radius, then when you are going straight or in an inflection point you have zero curvature and instead of infinite curvature radius.

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49521624/7328782

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To track a 2D curve, you should be using an expression for the [curvature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curvature) that is appropriate for general parametrized 2D functions.

While implementing the [equation from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curvature#In_terms_of_a_general_parametrization), you can use discrete differences to approximate the derivatives. Given the `x` and `y` coordinates, this could be implemented as follows:

```
% approximate 1st derivatives of x & y with discrete differences
dx  = 0.5*(x(3:end)-x(1:end-2))
dy  = 0.5*(y(3:end)-y(1:end-2))
dl  = sqrt(dx.^2 + dy.^2)
xp  = dx./dl
yp  = dy./dl
% approximate 2nd derivatives of x & y with discrete differences
xpp = (x(3:end)-2*x(2:end-1)+x(1:end-2))./(dl.^2)
ypp = (y(3:end)-2*y(2:end-1)+y(1:end-2))./(dl.^2)

% Compute the curvature
curvature = (xp.*ypp - yp.*xpp) ./ ((xp.^2 + yp.^2).^(1.5))
```

For demonstration purposes I've also constructed a synthetic test signal (which can be used to recreate the same conditions), but you can obviously use your own data instead:

```
z1 = linspace(2,1,N).*exp(1i*linspace(0.75*pi,-0.25*pi,N))
z2 = 2*exp(-1i*0.25*pi) + linspace(1,2,N)*exp(1i*linspace(0.75*pi,2.25*pi,N))
z = cat(1,z1,z2)
x = real(z)
y = imag(z)
```

[image: Sample trajectory]

With the corresponding curvature results:

[image: Curvature plot]

Comment: This is the right approach. But you should normalize the derivatives by the distance between samples. If each sample is exactly a unit distance from the previous sample, then your code is correct. Otherwise the magnitude of the curvature will be off.

Comment: @CrisLuengo good point, had me flip-flop on this one... The derivates are with respect to the parameter (`t` in [the formula on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curvature#In_terms_of_a_general_parametrization)) of the parametric equation (not with respect to the travelled path), so the code should give the correct curvature so long as the sampling is uniform (e.g. regular time intervals if travelling at constant speed; but then as you correctly pointed out in that case we might as well normalize with the path length).